docker push to Github: denied: Cookies must be enabled to use GitHub
Why does this fail with

denied: Cookies must be enabled to use GitHub.

❯ docker push github.com/foo/bar
Using default tag: latest
The push refers to repository [github.com/foo/bar]
5ecc437d208c: Preparing 
363a2b0467e6: Preparing 
9e06e5643b05: Preparing 
688d87829760: Preparing 
f4e05f790e71: Preparing 
4693057ce236: Waiting 
denied: Cookies must be enabled to use GitHub.


The domain is wrong. You need to use ghcr.io
❯ docker push ghcr.io/foo/bar
Using default tag: latest
The push refers to repository [ghcr.io/foo/bar]
5ecc437d208c: Pushed 
363a2b0467e6: Pushed 
9e06e5643b05: Pushed 
688d87829760: Pushed 
f4e05f790e71: Pushed 
latest: digest: sha256:02fe935ccc9a8f80ec8fab6218082b54f1799843bd89e57ca8917dc5d5381cd4 size: 1568

